# How do i implement moving up and down feature?

Tags: symfony

i need to rearrange the displayed items up by clicking on the up button displayed near each item
i tried /** @var DocumentManager $dm */
        $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();

```
    /** @var MaterializedPathRepository $repository */
    $repository = $dm->getRepository(Page::class);

    /* fetch page to swap with */
    /** @var Page $otherPage */
    $otherPage = $repository->findOneBy([
        'site' => $id->getSite()->getId(),
        'sort_index' => $id->getSortIndex()-1
    ]);


    if(null !== $otherPage) {
        $otherPage->setSortIndex($otherPage->getSortIndex()+1);
        $dm->persist($otherPage);
    }

    /* edit the sorting */
    $id->setSortIndex($id->getSortIndex()-1,$position);
    $dm->persist($id);
    $dm->flush();
```

but it is swapped with the last item..i need to move up one level..how can i do it?

Comment: It is for moving the displayed list of items up and down

Comment: Doctrine is for fetching data from database, not for moving items in client side. For that purpose you should use javascript.